# Read file by word, Scanner

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I have txt file, which each row contains two words, for example:

```
USA 321
France 1009
...
Germany 902
```

How can I read this file by word in two-dimensional array? I have:

```
List<List<String>> temps = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner dataScanner = new Scanner(dataFile);

while (dataScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    Scanner rowScanner = new Scanner(dataScanner.nextLine());
    temps.add(new ArrayList<>(2));

    while (rowScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use a Scanner for the row? If not, use `String.split()` to break the line up into words.

Comment: If you have to use a Scanner for the row, don't use `rowScanner.hasNextLine()`; it only contains one line. Use `hasNext()` (and `next()`) to get individual words from the line. Also, if you know for sure that each line will always have exactly 2 words, you can make your structure a `List<String[2]>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this assuming your code works

```
List<List<String>> temps = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner dataScanner = new Scanner(dataFile);

while (dataScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] data = dataScanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    temps.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(data[0],data[1]));
}
```

This takes the current line and splits it at a space character.
Afterwards it creates a list with the two elements and adds it to your temps list

Answer (score 1):

If you want absolutely use Scanner :

```
List<List<String>> temps = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner dataScanner = new Scanner("a b\nc d\ne f\n");

        while (dataScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner rowScanner = new Scanner(dataScanner.nextLine());
            List<String> datas=new ArrayList<>(2);
            temps.add(datas);

            while (rowScanner.hasNext("[^\\s]+")) {
                datas.add(rowScanner.next("[^\\s]+"));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to ALWAYS separate different functionalities in different functions. The code becomes easier to **read**, easier to **mantain** and **reusable**:

```
public static List<String> readFileLineByLine(String file) {
   List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
   while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      temps.add(scanner.nextLine());
   }
   return lines;
}

public static List<MyData> parseLines(List<String> lines) {
   List<MyData> list = new ArrayList<>();
   for (String line : lines) {
      String[] data = line.split(" ");
      list.add(new MyData(data[0], data[1]));
   }
   return list;
}
```

(Use `List<String>` as `MyData` if you need to)

Comment: Agree with you. In your code, i should add a function to only read one MyData to increase maintability and reusability

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of Scanner, but in this case you can get by reading line-by-line and using `String.split`. This becomes quite simple using streams. If you want to read into a two-dimensional array, you can do this:

```
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(FILENAME), UTF_8)) {
        String[][] result = lines.map(s -> s.split("\\s+"))
                                 .toArray(String[][]::new);
    }
```

Or if you want nested Lists, you can do this:

```
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(FILENAME), UTF_8)) {
        List<List<String>> result = lines.map(s -> s.split("\\s+"))
                                         .map(Arrays::asList)
                                         .collect(toList());
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```